# What is the best way to get country on install application

Tags: android, geolocation, installation

I want know, in which country application is installing, to setup first settings (currency, hide unsupported features in this country)

What is the best practise. I know about google geolocation. Maybe you know other? How google analytics gets country? From geolocation or ip?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch Location from Gps or Network and from Location u will get `Latitude and Longitude`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Locale.GetDefault()

See the doc here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html

**Edit**

Apologies hadn't read that you were after geo location.

Some excellent resource here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

you get get the mcc (mobile country code) out of the app's configuration like this:

```
int mcc = getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().mcc;
```

Here's a list of some mobile country codes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phone_number_series_by_country

Hope this helps :)